# MIPS "Unaligned address, Exception 5" error

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

I'm a noob using SPIM MIPS simulator.
I get the error in title X 26 times, when I try to initialize an array of 26 words to 0. I've isolated the problem to be the store word operation `sw $t0, 0($s3)`, but have no clue what am I doing wrong.

The code:

```
.data  
theArray: .space 104  
theArraySz: .word 26  
.text  
.globl main  
main:  
move    $t0, $zero  
la      $s3, theArray  
lw      $s4, theArraySz      
add     $t2, $zero  
initLoop:  
beq     $t2, $s4, initEnd       
sw      $t0, 0($s3)    
addi    $s3, $s3, 4        
addi    $t2, $t2, 1        
j       initLoop   
initEnd:        
jr $ra
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the address of `theArray` is aligned to a 32-bit word boundary. You can inspect the address if you have the ability to single-step through the program, and check the value of `$s3` after the first `la` instruction.

See [this wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/MIPS_Instructions#Directives) for documentation about alignment, and the `.align` directive that can be used to force alignment.

Comment: Ok, I now see how I step, and I see that after the la, $s3 holds the address 268500992:
"Reg 19 = 0x10010000 (268500992)"

Comment: Thanks, adding ".align 2" right after ".data" solved the problem (Please don't mind the previous comment).